How to reuse tests with different subjects-under-test in python?
This question is slightly different from Python unit test with base and sub class because the tests to be re-used exercise different subjects-under-test which are set by the subclasses
I have multiple implementations of the same functionality and want to reuse the test cases:
What I have so far is:
class TestBase(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, sut: Callable[[int], int]):
        super().__init__()

        self.sut = sut

    def test_1(self):
        expected = 1

        n = 1

        actual = self.sut(n)

        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)

    def test_2(self):
        expected = 2

        n = 2

        actual = self.sut(n)

        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)


class TestImplA(TestBase):
    def setUp(self):
        super().sut = impl_a


class TestImplB(TestBase):
    def setUp(self):
        super().sut = impl_b

but no actual tests are being run with the above.
I've tried customizing TestBase.__init__ (including using **kwargs) with no luck
How can I go about parameterizing TestBase?

If you want your test methods (test_2() etc) to call different methods at the lines self.sut(n), then just override them in your subclasses.

The issue lies in the way you're trying to parameterize TestBase. The unittest framework creates test case instances dynamically, and __init__ is not the appropriate place to pass arguments for parameterization. Instead, you should use a factory pattern to dynamically create test cases for different implementations.
It's a solution using unittest.TestCase and dynamically creating test classes for your implementation:
import unittest
from typing import Callable

# Define your TestBase class
class TestBase(unittest.TestCase):
    sut: Callable[[int], int]

    def test_1(self):
        expected = 1
        n = 1
        actual = self.sut(n)
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)

    def test_2(self):
        expected = 2
        n = 2
        actual = self.sut(n)
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)

# Factory function to create test classes
def create_test_case(name: str, sut: Callable[[int], int]):
    class CustomTestCase(TestBase):
        @classmethod
        def setUpClass(cls):
            cls.sut = sut

    CustomTestCase.__name__ = name
    return CustomTestCase

# Example implementations
def impl_a(n: int) -> int:
    return n

def impl_b(n: int) -> int:
    return n * 2  # Incorrect intentionally to demonstrate failure

# Dynamically create test cases
TestImplA = create_test_case("TestImplA", impl_a)
TestImplB = create_test_case("TestImplB", impl_b)

# Run tests
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()


This doesn't work. It tries to use TestBase itself as a test case, raises exceptions on the other test cases, and doesn't name the test cases correctly.

Remove the TestBase.__init__ definition. TestBase should look like:
class TestBase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        expected = 1

        n = 1

        actual = self.sut(n)

        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)

    def test_2(self):
        expected = 2

        n = 2

        actual = self.sut(n)

        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)

This will cause issues since the tests in TestBase will still be run and TestBase.sut isn't defined, though
The answers in Python unit test with base and sub class suggest various ways to resolve that
